# How to set some part of the registry back to standard in a company?

Tags: windows-registry

After migration to new domain some registry setting got scrambled.
The standard programm are not working correctly anymore everytime jpg gets opened you get the list with all avaible programms.
Our research so far resulted in finding out that this happened because the setting in the registry are not correct anymore.

One way we got one PC working again was importing the default registry downloaded from this site: https://www.eightforums.com/threads/default-file-associations-restore-in-windows-8.8486/
Sadly its not an official site so we are hesistant using these files company wide.

Is there some other possible solution? Some way to do it with the GPO so that we don't have to do it for every user?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So only solution seems to be:
- Open regedit as the user not as a admin!

- Go to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/FileExts/
- Here open each file extension that makes problem and delete the folder UserChoice
- User has to redefine standards once afterswards it works without problems.

In theory the user could do it themself because no admin is needed.